# ESP32 WROVER-B programming issue

Tags: esp32

trying to program ESP32-WROVER-B it stops just after start, I have connected button EN (on pin EN) and tried various combinations but it didn't help.
Also tried to change baudrate, fix flash size to 4MB but still nothing.
This is the output:

```
$ make -j4 flash monitor
Toolchain path: /opt/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc
Toolchain version: crosstool-ng-1.22.0-80-g6c4433a5
Compiler version: 5.2.0
App "websocket_server" version: b4b6984-dirty
Python requirements from C:/ESP32/esp-idf/requirements.txt are satisfied.
Flashing binaries to serial port COM8 (app at offset 0x10000)...
esptool.py v2.6-beta1
Serial port COM8
Connecting........_____..
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ5 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
MAC: 24:6f:28:4c:9b:4c
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 230400
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Compressed 24240 bytes to 14517...
Wrote 24240 bytes (14517 compressed) at 0x00001000 in 0.7 seconds (effective 295.4 kbit/s)...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header
make: *** [/c/ESP32/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/Makefile.projbuild:63: flash] Error 2
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your ESP32 looks like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NKXHT5F)  you need to keep pressed the RST button while uploading the new code to avoid that error.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Judging from logs, reset button in that case should be pressed when at `Connecting` line, I think this smells more like a dead chip or unstable power supply.